# Get request on button click

Tags: php, html, request

here is the challenge, I have a webpage, with a form in it , and the button that corresponds to it of course causes a submit. The other button that I have, essentially must trigger a database call that displays content from the database, on this page.

So technically my mind understands that this button should send a GET request to the server and then I retrieve the necessary information and it is displayed. But syntactically, I do not understand how to pull this off, one way to go about doing it is to encapsulate this button in another form, that has a method called GET, and in my server side, I retrieve my information, encode it and send it back to the client. But the idea of encoding this inside a form does not appeal to me as this isn't a form, all I really want to understand is how I can trigger the GET method by clicking a button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are two simple ways to send a GET request. One is as you figured out, a new form that has that button as an input and nothing is wrong with that so I'm not sure what is not appealing to you. The second way could be via link, for example:

```
<a href="somesite.php?something=value">Link</a>
```

Comment: because technically a form is meant to hold data and submit it, so it does not appeal to my programming aesthetics :(, your answer is correct, I weirdly forgot about hyperlinks helping me out on this..thanks...